# Best Randomness equation

Tags: random

I have to write an algorithm based on current random generation standards. I mean, I have to choose an existing one and coupling with various factors(may be by means learning of existing facts). So what is the best place to start reading about random generators. I know Wiki, but to have a finite start I must read some articles or papers. Moreover, I need a quick start. What are the current existing Random Generators and what factors they consider? How feasible to impose facts on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current algorithms do not generate **random** numbers. They generate **pseudo**-random numbers. Which is not the same thing.

**Random** number can be normally obtained from nature using some kind of hardware. For example, if you read sound level from FM-tuner that is tuned to receive atmospheric noise, number will be quite random. Example of such generator is [random.org](http://www.random.org/). You could also implement dice-throwing or coin-flipping robot or [something similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator). On linux you can use /dev/random that uses user to generate random events.

To determine if **pseudo**-random number generator produces high quality randomness that can be used for cryptography, data produced by PRNG should pass prng tests such as [this](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html). That is not easy and many PRNGs fail miserably on them. One of the algorithms that produces relatively high-quality **pseudo**-random numbers while remaining easy to implement is [XorShift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). However, easy implementation doesn't mean that it is easy to understand [logic](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper) behind this particular generator.

> Moreover, I need a quick start.

As with every subject quick start would be to go to wikipedia and start reading all the reference for the subject, or google it. So far it seems you haven't tried to do that.

> I know Wiki

No you don't. If you "knew wiki" you'd knew that at the end of every article is list of sources used to write article. Read the sources.

Comment: The cryptographic PRNGs in operating systems are still PRNGs but based on outside-world entropy. On Linux you can even draw numbers from the entropy pool directly which is definitely random not pseudo-random. And there are still algorithms involved.

Comment: Random advice in that regard to the one asking the question: Read the papers introducing the generators you read on Wikipedia. And then do a breadth-first reading of the referenced papers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no idea what you are doing (your question doesn't sound like you're someone like L'Ecuyer or Marsaglia), then stay far away from modifying or combining PRNGs. You're more likely to hurt the quality of the generators than improve it.

This advice is even more valid if you were talking about crytopgraphic PRNGs.